# How to start a POD in Kubernetes when another blocks an important resource?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I'm getting stuck in the configuration of a deployment. The problem is the following.

The application in the deployment is using a database which is stored in a file. While this database is open, it's locked (there's no way for read/write access for many).

If I delete the running POD the new one can't get in ready state, because the database is still locked. I read about preStop-Hook and tried to use it without success.

I could delete the lock file, which seems to be pretty harsh. What's the right way to solve this in Kubernetes?

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for the leader election pattern.
Instead of locking the resource, you allow your pod to access it only if it wins the leader election process.
When a pod terminates, the leader lease will eventually expire and the new pod can claim it.
See for example https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/01/simple-leader-election-with-kubernetes/

Comment: Which database system are you using? Can you share the preStop you tried?

Comment: I did some experiments with DuckDB. I tried this one: https://blog.gruntwork.io/gracefully-shutting-down-pods-in-a-kubernetes-cluster-328aecec90d

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't different than running this process outside of Kubernetes. When the pod is killed, it will be given a chance to shutdown cleanly. So the lock should be cleaned up. If the lock isn't cleaned up, there's not a lot of ways you can determined if the lock remains because an unclean shutdown was made, or a node is unhealthy, or if there is a network partition. So deleting the lock at pod startup does seem to be unwise.

I think the first step for you should be trying to determine why this lock file isn't getting cleaned up correctly. (Rather than trying to address the symptom.)

Comment: Thanks, David! POD 1 will only be terminated (including a shutdown of DB connection), when POD 2 is ready. POD 2 can only be ready if it has a DB connection. The leader election pattern (see above) was a good hint.